# Best way to implement Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I suffer a lot in the past with angular apps and social media, so I'm glad to see that Angular Universal is being developed.

Currently I have some apps that are Angular4 as front end, and Java with Spring as backend. As far as I know there are some ways to implement Angular Universal here but they seem pretty complex (at least is what I read). So I want to know if that is in that way or not...

But anyway, my main question here, is because I saw that in order to implement Angular Universal we should have (ideally) to make the backend with nodejs, how to structure these two technologies, I mean... Should I have Angular app as a frontend app and Nodejs app as a totally different backend app (just like Java) where both are connected with web services? Or should I served Angular4 SPA direcly from Nodejs views?
And where should I place Angular Universal here?

Answer (score 2):

Now that **Angular CLI v1.6** is out, there's native support for building Angular Universal into your projects easily using Node.js!  Essentially, you would ng build --prod to create a dist/ folder, and then create a simple node back-end and connect to your dist/ folder containing your front-end code.  This article gives a great step-by-step guide: [Angular server-side rendering in Node with Express Universal Engine](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/angular-server-side-rendering-in-node-with-express-universal-engine-dce21933ddce).

Comment: Yeah... but my question.. is more about the architecture... should they be 2 total different apps, or the nodejs backend should be the one responsible for serving the views?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, Nodejs serves the Angular SPA directly from Nodejs views.  If you look at the `server.js` file on the above website, `app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/dist`));` is how Angular is connected to Nodejs.  The Angular Express engine then sets these views using `app.set('views', 'dist');`.  The entire application is a single app that is served on `http://localhost:3000` or `process.env.PORT` depending on your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Angular Universal, it is going to be a single process (Operating system process) that hosts and serves your Angular pages.

In production you may have multiple such processes behind a load-balancer.

Your back-end APIs (if developed in Javascript) may be hosted in the same Node server or in separate server.

The Angular Universal setup steps are detailed [here](https://angular.io/guide/universal) in the official documentation.

However, I had a few wasted hours to find out the following point

- Webpack 3 is not compatible with ts-loader versions higher than 3.5.0. At the time of developing this, the latest version of Angular CLI is 1.7.2 which uses Webpack 3.*. Hence, while setting up Angular Universal, install ts-config@3.5.0

Finally, [here](https://github.com/saptarshibasu/angular-universal-setup) I have a seed project for Angular Universal. It uses Vagrant to locally setup the development environment. Also, by tweaking an environment variable in your local host machine, you can run it in a production mode in a Docker container. The steps to run it are detailed in the readme file.

If you refer to my Dockerfile in the above Github link, its entrypoint reads:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["pm2-runtime","start","/home/aus/dist/server.js"]
```

So, you see, it's just a singe command, and your app is up and running at port 4000. Of course you can use other command line parameters to provide memory limit, port and so on.